# Draw a circular distorted shape in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

I am still very new to vector and I wanted to make something similar to this image.

[image]

I want to make it as circular shape. The only idea I got is to manually draw it point by point. Any better techniques?

using Adobe Illustrator.

Thank you

Comment: Draw a normal circle, apply to the stroke a brush from Illustrator's collection of  artistic brushes. Learn also how to make your own brushes - only draw something horizontal, drag it to the brushes collection and define the brush type. Some good ones can be made by using scanned real brush strokes as bitmap or traced to vector.

Answer (score 4):

Simply draw a rounded rectangle and apply a **Brush stroke** to the path.

[image]

There are a number of brushes which ship with AI. You can probably find one which suits your need.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a "round-rect" with a simple brush stroke applied to the stroke... could be done in any vector editor which supports brushes - could be Illustrator, or Affinity Designer, or InkScape.

In all three of those vector art apps, there are ellipse tools; in almost all cases with pre-canned shape tools, when you hold shift as you pull out, this will constrain the aspect ratio to 1:1. So if you choose a rectangle tool and pull holding shift, you get a square; if you choose an ellipse tool and pull holding shift, you get a circle.

Then apply a brush you like, and you should be all set.

Like so:
[image]

Hope that helps.